# SimpleXMLElement out of memory with more files

Tags: php, simplexml

I build a script which have multi curl and extract code souce from multiple urls. It works fine with a few links but if I want to add how I want.. maybe 1000 urls, after 100urls parsed my script crash because is out of memory(ram)

my code:

```
...
try {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    foreach ($xml->url as $url_list) {
        $url = $url_list->loc;
        $newurls[] = $url;
        unset($xml);
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "invalid";
}
}
```

My $data variable is the result of source code for each url which was get with multi curl.
Is there a way to clear the memory or something?
I already tried to allocate memory from php.ini, the problem is not there.

Comment: How about break down the operation into separate cron job? As cURL needs to wait for server's response, it may hold up a lot of RAM for multiple URL. Recommended to use cron job to execute them one-by-one and process the result.

Comment: Why are you destroying $xml continuously within the loop?

Comment: I was thinking it will help me to reduce ram memory.